# Detecting if the position of pointer is inside the Widget or not onPointerUp event

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am creating a widget that behaves like a button, I would like for it to know if the touch point is outside of it or not when the touch lifted, like so.  Any thoughts please ?

```
Listener(
  onPointerMove: (event) {

  },
  onPointerDown: (event) {
  },
  onPointerUp: (event) {
    //Detect if the position of the pointer is still inside or not
  },
  child: Container(
    width: 200, height: 200,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a GestureDetector to listen to drag events, which will give you the exact position of the pointer (when it's pressed down), and compare that to the size of the widget (which you can get by adding a key to the widget itself).

Here is some sample code to give you an idea of what I mean:

Edit: Updated code

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  bool touchIsInside = true;
  GlobalKey touchKey = new GlobalKey();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: GestureDetector(
        key: touchKey,
        onTap: () {
          print("Handle regular tap.");
        },
        onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
          if (touchKey.currentContext == null ||
              touchKey.currentContext?.size == null) return;
          if (touchKey.currentContext!.size!.width < details.localPosition.dx ||
              details.localPosition.dx < 0 ||
              touchKey.currentContext!.size!.height <
                  details.localPosition.dy ||
              details.localPosition.dy < 0) {
            touchIsInside = false;
          } else {
            touchIsInside = true;
          }
        },
        onPanEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {
          if (touchIsInside) {
            print("Handle press ended inside.");
          } else {
            print("Handle press ended outside.");
          }
          touchIsInside = true;
        },
        child: Container(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
              child: Text(
                "Press me!",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
            color: Colors.blue),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can check a demo of it out here: https://screenrec.com/share/sWHt2zk5SV

Comment: This works partially, when the touch is outside of the width of the button, it knows it is outside, but when the touch is outside of the height, it doesnt work

Comment: @JayVDiyk Probably because I've only added horizontal drag listeners. You can add the same code for vertical drag listeners as well simultaneously and it should work. Or you could use the pan listeners. I'll make a change to the code for your benefit.

Comment: @JayVDiyk It would seem there was a bug in the code. I wasn't checking for cases where the value was going below zero. Take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Your code seems to be logically correct, but the same problem still exists. Try dragging it slowly outside the button to reproduce

Comment: But i am accepting this answer nevertheless

Comment: @JayVDiyk Thanks. I'll look into the issue you've mentioned in a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a MouseRegion widget to keep track of whether the pointer has entered/exited the container:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MouseRegion-class.html

In onEnter you could just set a variable to indicate the pointer is within the region, and set it to false in onExit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this doesnt work on touch event, e.g.: when the touch dragged and exit the widget